# why does my 'click' addEventListener getting called on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, event-handling, addeventlistener

I have a button with id #login and a javascript file with this line:

```
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', 'LoginPressed()')
```

As a test, I made this function:

```
function LoginPressed(){
  console.log('was login pressed already??')
}
```

And my function is getting called every time the page loads. How do I stop that from happening?

Note, I've also tried the callback not in quotes, and not as a function:

```
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', LoginPressed())
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', LoginPressed)
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', 'LoginPressed')
```

Comment: Are you using jquery as you have included that tag? If so does $('#login'). on('click', function () {}) work?

Comment: You can try: `document.getElementById('login').onclick=LoginPressed;` i have used it in `setInterval`, all was good.

Comment: @Igor Using event properties is discouraged. It's not in line with the W3C DOM Level 2 standard and limits the capabilities of event handling. Also, even if one was to use it, it has zero connection with `setInterval`. `addEventListener` is the proper technique.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `setInterval` was used because of ajax: http://pastebin.com/Z4zq2h6Q

Comment: @Igor AJAX has no direct relationship with `setInterval`. To be clear, you may have used these things together, but neither requires the other.

Comment: @EJW  The second syntax at the end of your post is the correct syntax. **If you are having a problem with that, you must have a problem somewhere else in your code.** See my answer below for a working version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are ***invoking*** it, rather than ***referencing*** it.

This:

```
 document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', 'LoginPressed()');
```

Should be this:

```
 document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', LoginPressed);
```

There should not be parenthesis after `LoginPressed` because you only want to refer to the the function so that it can be known that this is the function to call later. With parenthesis there, you are invoking it right away.

There should also not be quotes around LoginPressed as this is the actual name of the function. With the quotes there, the JavaScript runtime won't recognize the function properly.

**Here's your code, correctly written and working (notice how the console message does not appear until you click the button):**

```js
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', LoginPressed)

function LoginPressed(){
  console.log('was login pressed already??')
}
```

```html
<button id="login">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I agree as only adding parentheses after function name calls it immediately